# Python connect to rest api

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, rest, python-requests

i want to connect to a rest api with the following code:

```
data = requests.get("http://pbx/rest/login").json()
head = {'loginType' : 'Internal','nonce' : data["nonce"], 'secret' : (hashlib.sha1((LOGIN_ID+data['nonce']+PASSWORD).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest())}
data_new = requests.post('http://pbx/rest/login',data=head)
print(data_new)
```

requesting the nonce from the pbx just works fine, then i need to generate the login secret and have to post it to the pbx and the answer should be a token

but print(data_new) jus shows me  and print(data_new.json()) crashes with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "starface.py", line 14, in <module>
    Connect()
  File "starface.py", line 12, in Connect
    data_new = requests.post(SERVER+"login",data=head).json()
  File "C:\Users\BüroNotebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site
-packages\requests\models.py", line 866, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BüroNotebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json
\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\BüroNotebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json
\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\BüroNotebook\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json
\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you get a blank response body and there's nothing to parse. Here's a snippet to get the same json error:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads('')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 343, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/json/decoder.py", line 361, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Expecting value", s, err.value)) from None
ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

So I would do the following:

1. `print(d.headers, d.status_code)`. You'd see your HTTP response code and maybe something helpful in response headers. With this information in mind check out docs for your pbx server to figure out what it means and then maybe fix something in the way you're bulding your second request.
2. if you have access to the log files check what's happening there. If you don't have this access reach out to somebody who has it